# using Active Record .where in Rails to find table records that have nil value in column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a Tool model and in the Tool table there is a rent_price column. I am trying to find all the Tools that have nil in their price column.

I am running this in my console

```
example = Tool.where("rent_price = 'nil'")
```

I want all those tools to be in my example variable so I can see them. However I get the following:

```
irb(main):009:0> example = Tool.where("rent_price = 'nil'")
  Tool Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "tools".* FROM "tools" WHERE (rent_price = 'nil')
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

What does this mean? How can I access all my tools with nil for rent_price. I can see there are records that have this but cant put them all together in one collection. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you putting the nil value in quotes? are you looking for the String "nil"?

Did you try:

```
example = Tool.where(rent_price: nil)
```

?

Also, if your SQL refers to nil as NULL, as Mu pointed out, you could write the SQL:

```
example = Tool.where("rent_price is NULL")
```

Comment: This is database specific. I seem to remember that some databases accepted = NULL (or did)... This is a good example for why abstraction in ActiveRecord is the preferred way to write conditional SELECT statements.